# How to run SQL Query in List variable python?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have CLOB column which has SQL query. I get the CLOB column in Oracle database as a list variable you can see the below

```py
for row in cur:

    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame([[row[0].read()]],
                        columns=["cogipf_requeststring"])
    df = df.append(df_tmp, ignore_index=True)

List_df = df[['cogipf_requeststring']].values.tolist()
```

List_df

```
[['SELECT DISTINCT "COGNOS_DASHBOARD_EVENT"."EVENT_TITLE" AS "Event_Title", "COGNOS_DASHBOARD_EVENT"."EVENT_CONTENT" AS "Event_Content" FROM "COGNOS"."COGNOS_DASHBOARD_EVENT" "COGNOS_DASHBOARD_EVENT" WHERE "COGNOS_DASHBOARD_EVENT"."EVENT_TYPE" = 2 AND "COGNOS_DASHBOARD_EVENT"."EVENT_PERIOD" = 201903']]
```

How can i run this query with `cur.execute`?
If i achieve the run this query, i want to export the result as a Excel workbook
Do you have any suggestion about this situation ?